# Display directives (in lines) from config file that aren't in an another config using bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell, openwrt

There are similar questions like this, but this is specific, and my awk knowledge isn't good at all (though you can use any tool for this).
So, I'm working with OpenWRT config files. 1st file looks like this (this is the initial config of my build (a part of it)):

```
# Use "make defconfig" to expand this to a full .config

# Selecting target and model(s)
CONFIG_TARGET_ar71xx=y
CONFIG_TARGET_ar71xx_generic_ARCHERC7=y

CONFIG_PACKAGE_luci-ssl=y

# we do not need these, since it adds more dependencies
#CONFIG_PACKAGE_mc=y
```

As you can see the directives (e.g. 'CONFIG_PACKAGE_luci-ssl') usually have value in this file (but this doesn't matter), but they can be commented out, and can be empty lines in it.
Let's say the 2nd config file looks like this (just a basic full config):

```
#
# Automatically generated file; DO NOT EDIT.
# OpenWrt Configuration
#
CONFIG_MODULES=y
CONFIG_HAVE_DOT_CONFIG=y
# CONFIG_TARGET_ppc40x is not set
# CONFIG_TARGET_realview is not set
# CONFIG_TARGET_atheros is not set
CONFIG_TARGET_ar71xx=y
# CONFIG_TARGET_ar71xx_generic_ARCHERC7 is not set
```

In the 2nd config the directives usually don't have values (these times they are commented out) but sometimes they can have.

I want to display all uncommented directives (with or without their values (doesn't matter)) from the 1st file that aren't in the second file at all whether they are commented out or uncommented.
In this example it'd only display:

```
CONFIG_PACKAGE_luci-ssl
```

It's good for having an initial config file, and when you upgrade to an another release you can easily test whether you can use your config or not with that release (is there any missing settings).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the files are named `1st` and `2nd`, this is one possibility:

```
grep -vf<(echo ^#;echo ^$;sed -n 's/.*=y/^&/p;s/# \(.*\) is not set/^\1=/p' 2nd) 1st
```

The commands in between `<(` `)` generate a list of patterns that are searched for in `1st`:

- `^#` lines beginning with `#`
- `^$` lines beginning and immediately ending, i. e. empty
- `^.*=` lines beginning with directives from `2nd`

Due to option `-v`, these matching lines are not displayed, leaving the wanted non-matching lines.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (I came up with my solution in the meantime), but it doesn't work: `FILE1="../configs/init.config"; FILE2=".config"; grep -vf<(echo ^#;echo ^$;sed -n 's/.*=y/^&/p;s/# \(.*\) is not set/^\1=/p' "$FILE2") "$FILE1"`

Comment: @Krisztian - Would you care for telling in what way it doesn't work? - When I try it with the example files in question, it displays `CONFIG_PACKAGE_luci-ssl=y`, as you wanted.

Comment: sorry about this, you are right, I forgot what I wanted in the first place, I accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
FILE1="../configs/init.config"; FILE2=".config"; grep -v "^#" "$FILE1" | grep -v "^$" | grep -F -x -v -f "$FILE2" -
```

Comment: This approach, used with the example files in question, displays `CONFIG_TARGET_ar71xx_generic_ARCHERC7=y` and
`CONFIG_PACKAGE_luci-ssl=y`, the former of which it shouldn't, according to your specification.

Comment: You are right. I use this to check the final generated config whether any wanted (in 1st file) setting missing from it.